# Implicit chunk serialization is disabled to prevent unpredictable performance degradation

Tags: omnet++

When I write the implementation of gptp, when I send a message, I find that when I send a message from eth [] to IPv4, the following error will appear in the IP of IPv4:

> <!> Implicit chunk serialization is disabled to prevent unpredictable performance degradation (you may consider changing the Chunk::enableImplicitChunkSerialization flag or passing the PF_ ALLOW_ SERIALIZATION flag to peek) -- in module (inet::Ipv4) Test.gPtpSlave0.ipv4.ip (id=103), at t=0.00001157s, event #14

This is my omnetpp.ini::

```
[General]
simtime-resolution = fs

network = Test

**.configurator.assignDisjunctSubnetAddresses = false
**.configurator.addStaticRoutes = false
**.configurator.addSubnetRoutes = true
**.configurator.addDefaultRoutes = true
**.configurator.optimizeRoutes = false
**.configurator.dumpAddresses = true
**.configurator.dumpRoutes = true


#**.gPtpMaster.gptp.typename = "gPtp"
#**.gptp.typename = "gPtp"

**.eth[*].mac.promiscuous = true

**.ethernet.typename = "EthernetLayer"
**.standardHost*.encap.typename = ""
*.gPtpMaster.gptp.typename = "gPtp"
*.gPtpBridge0.gptp.typename = "gPtp"
*.gPtpSlave0.gptp.typename = "gPtp"


**.gPtpMaster.hasTcp = false
**.gPtpSlave0.hasTcp = false


*.gPtpMaster.gptp.masterPorts = "eth0"
*.gPtpBridge0.gptp.slavePort = "eth0"
*.gPtpSlave0.gptp.slavePort = "eth0"

*.gPtpBridge0.gptp.masterPorts = "eth1"


*.gPtpMaster.clock.clockDrift = 0
*.gPtpBridge0.clock.clockDrift = 30
*.gPtpSlave0.clock.clockDrift = -50
```

Does somebody knows how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The common reason for this error is that you add some kind of chunk to the packet and then that chunk is popped or peeked as a completely different type of chunk. The two types are unrelated so there is no way to convert between the two. The only way would be to serialize the chunk and then deserialize at the other end (not that that would give you any meaningful results of course). The information you provided here is not enough to give you answer. You should debug your code. Try to get to the point where the error happens (event #14) and look into the packet content (in Qtenv, you can dissect the packet in properties view and see what is inside the packet). Then check your code and see if that is compatible with the packet content.